# execute a function several times until it is different from 400

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes a few seconds to get the URL. How could I make this function run several times until it is different from the 400 error, I was thinking of using a while loop but I can't find a way to solve it

```
async function getUrl() {
try {
    let res = await fetch(myURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    });
    if (res.ok) {
        return await res.json();
    } else {        
        return 400;
    }
} catch (error) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to attempt up to a max number of times (pass `Infinity` for approximately an infinite amount of tries). The `return` statement will automatically break out of the loop so you don't have to try to do anything complicated with the for loop conditional. Between each attempt, it waits `delayMs` milliseconds. Set it to 0 if you want, but you probably want at least a second (1000 ms) between each.

`myUrl` should probably be a parameter to this, so I added it, but feel free to remove it.

```js
async function getUrl(myUrl, maxTries, delayMs) {
  let res;
  for (let tries = 0; tries < maxTries; tries++) {
    try {
      res = await fetch(myURL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {}
    if (res.status != 400) {
      return await res.json();
    }
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs));
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Should probably add a delay between requests, or a limit on how many retries are acceptable.

Comment: How could I add the delay or limit the number of retries ? thank you

Comment: @streaming-coc okay i added those